# Integration by using special functions

Tags: integration, special-functions, gamma-function

$$\int ^{\pi }_{0}\dfrac {dt}{\sqrt {3-\cos t}}$$

How can you solve the following equation by using alpha/gamma functions and putting

$$\cos t=1-2\sqrt {u}$$

Comment: This is just the definition of the elliptical integral of the first kind K(m).  We have
$$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{3-\cos t}} =\sqrt{2} K(-1).
$$
See here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html.

Comment: There is no closed form for this integral

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd t \over \root{3 - \cos\pars{t}}}}&=
\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd t \over \root{3 - \bracks{1 - 2\sin^{2}\pars{t/2}}}}
=\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd t \over \root{2 + 2\sin^{2}\pars{t/2}}}
\\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd t \over \root{2 + 2\sin^{2}\pars{t}}}
=\root{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd t \over \root{1 + \sin^{2}\pars{t}}}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large\root{2}\,{\rm K}\pars{-1}}
\end{align}
where
$\ds{{\rm K}\pars{m} = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}{\dd t \over \root{1 - m\,\sin^{2}\pars{t}}}}$
is the [Elliptic Integral of the First Kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Answer (score 1):

Maple does this using EllipticK:

> int(1/sqrt(3-cos(t)),t=0..Pi);
$$  \text{EllipticK}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\right)$$

> select(has,[FunctionAdvisor(specialize,%)],GAMMA);
$$
[[{\rm EllipticK} \left( \dfrac12\sqrt {2} \right) =\dfrac12{\frac {{\pi }^{
3/2}}{  \Gamma  \left( 3/4 \right)   ^{2}}},\mbox { 
`with no restrictions`}]]
$$